# How to check file not modified/corrupted during downloading from ftp/http/https using php

Tags: java, php, .net, checksum, md5sum

I just want to make sure downloaded files are 100% same as in server. I am using php program to download files from server using  ftp/http/https  protocols.

I am checking following checks for ftp.

```
-File size 
-Last Modified date
```

For HTTP/HTTPS
I am not sure what I need to check as file size can't determine before download.

Also for all protocols I am not sure how to check checksum/md5sum/sh1sum to make sure file is not corrupted and not modified.

Note: our file sizes are very large(even some of them are in GBs).

Please suggest me to make sure 100% quality check for file.

Comment: you can not determine after download either